# Debian Dockerfile - changing the locale to UTF-8

Tags: docker, dockerfile, debian

I have a Docker container for a MySQL database, where I need to fix a problem with the locale. When I execute the locale command in the docker image, I get the following results:

```
# locale 
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

I want to change it to UTF-8 because the current configuration probably causes a problem.
Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:8.0.33-debian

COPY mysql-repository.gpg mysql-repository.gpg


RUN apt-key add mysql-repository.gpg
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dirmngr gpg curl gawk git python3 python3-venv locales
RUN git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git $HOME/.asdf --branch v0.11.1
RUN echo ". $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh" >> $HOME/.bashrc

RUN sed -i '/C.UTF-8/s/^# //g' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

WORKDIR /root

COPY install_asdf_packages.sh install_asdf_packages.sh
COPY .tool-versions .tool-versions

RUN bash -l install_asdf_packages.sh

RUN echo 'export PATH=/root/.venv/bin:${PATH}' >> $HOME/.bashrc

COPY tws.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/tws.cnf
RUN chmod 644 /etc/mysql/conf.d/tws.cnf

WORKDIR /

COPY db-transfer.sh db-transfer.sh
RUN chmod +x db-transfer.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "./db-transfer.sh" ]
```

How do I change the locale to UTF-8? The RUN sed -i command and setting the ENV value didn't change anything.

Comment: I think your using the `ENV` command wrong. Did you look at the [Dockerfile reference?](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)?

Comment: Have you tried using the modern way of declaring variables and not the legacy way? Also, with quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
...

ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_US

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN printf '%s\n' LANG=en_US LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 >/etc/default/locale
RUN echo en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 >>/etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen
```

---

I started to write an answer involving `dpkg-reconfigure locales` but it turns out there are multiple bugs around this which remain unsolved since many years back.

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684134
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=500164

```
# FIXME: broken
RUN printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' \
    locales locales/locales_to_be_generated \
        multiselect "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" \
    locales locales/default_environment_locale \
        select "en_US.UTF8" | \
    debconf-set-selections && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

after the installation of `locales`, obviously.